# Typescript - Conditional property of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, properties, conditional-statements

I have the following object to which I wish to have a conditional property:

```
{ name: this.username, DOB: new Date(this.inputDate)}
```

Say, I wish to add a third property called gender if the user has specified their gender. What would the proper syntax for the following be:

```
{ name: this.username, DOB: new Date(this.inputDate), if(this.userGender) gender: this.userGender}
```

P.S. I **do not** wish to have the `gender` property in my object if there is no value along with it. So how can I only create the property if the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just assign userGender conditionally?   `let myObject = { /*object without gender */ }; if(this.userGender) myObject.gender = this.userGender;`

Comment: Its available in Dart - I wish it could be introduced into typescript

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ideally, you would just add the appropriate property as a second action after declaring your object. So something like:

```
const myObj = {
    name: this.username,
    DOB: new Date(this.inputDate),
}

if(this.userGender) myObj.gender = this.userGender;
```

However, sometimes it's nice to declare an "optional" property inline with the rest of them, in which case you can use object spread to get the effect you're looking for:

```
const myObj = {
    name: this.username,
    DOB: new Date(this.inputDate),

    ...this.userGender && { gender: this.userGender }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the first form works in TypeScript: `Property 'gender' does not exist on type '{ name: string; DOB: Date; }'.`

Comment: You can also use `undefined` instead of `{}` as `{ ...undefined }` has the same effect as `{ ...{} }` (empty object)

Comment: in which case, we can do `...this.userGender && { gender: this.userGender }`

Comment: Adding properties to an already existing object at runtime is a bad idea because it slows down JavaScript. The reason is that in this case the JavaScript runtime environment will have build a history chain of the object. Why? Because you could access the object at different times resulting in different closures and versions of the object. Doing this a lot in your code is the biggest and most overlooked performance problem in applications.

Answer (score 19):

it can be done like this too, more clean and readable.

```js
const myObj = {
    name: this.username,
    DOB: new Date(this.inputDate),
    ...(this.userGender && { gender : this.userGender })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let userObj = { name: this.username, DOB: new Date(this.inputDate) }
if(this.userGender) 
    userObj["gender"] = this.userGender;
```

Comment: What does :gender do on the last line?  I can't see where that's described in any documentation.

Comment: This (the `:gender` part) doesn't appear to be valid TS.

Comment: Updated the answer, ignore : it was a normal string